# Discomfort but not pain in joints

Tags: running, injury, pain

This is easier to explain with a specific example: let's say you've had jumper's knee (Patellar tendinitis) in the past caused by running. Pain underneath the knee that comes on during a run and afterwards.

You've healed but now sometimes have "discomfort" but not pain after working out. Or perhaps not even pain but "it feels weird."

Is there any medical study of such weirdness that doesn't lead to pain? A term for it? My assumption would be it's a forewarning of future problems you can get on top of, but maybe sometimes things just feel strange.

Comment: I am somewhat reluctant to close this, but it's not really a fitness question. I don't think it would really fit on Biology or Medical Science, either. It's interesting, and would make a great chat topic, but I don't think it's really a good fit for the site. I'll leave it open for the community, at least for now.

Comment: @JohnP Reasonable, it's extremely speculative. I do think there's value is identifying what's pain compared to discomfort and feeling odd, and what is a tell leading up to an injury. I'm open to really any rephrasing that gets to a reasonable question and answer that fits this forum.

Comment: I've been thinking, and it all really boils down to listening to and knowing your body. I know what aches are normal after various types of workouts, and when something is "not right" and I need to rest or rehab it a bit. But all of those indicators are really person to person based, and will be different for everyone.

Comment: A rule of thumb in physiotherapy practice (heard it from a knee specialist in a podcast) is that if there is no pain that persists for more than two hours after the workout, it is fine. Generally, I'd advise against thinking too much about your knee bc that (ie. constant consious perception and focus) is what makes pain, loss of function, and both of them as chronic states, more probable.